# No such module 'StarscreamSocketIO'

Tags: swift, socket.io

I was working on an ios app where I'm trying to listen to a flask server. I'm trying to use web sockets for this purpose. So I followed some blog posts and tried to `Socket.io-Client-swift` for my purpose. Till now it is fine. But when I try to build, xcode interpreter is throwing error: `No such module StarscreamSocketIO`. Apparently, both of the frameworks work toward the same goal but I could not understand the glue between these two so that I can make my app work using websockets. I followed all the instructions given in their github pages but still I'm not successful. [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) and [Socket.io-client-swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) are the two frameworks. I don't understand how some blog posts were successful in doing so. Has anybody faced this kind of error?

Comment: did you do `import Starscream` and `import SocketIO`?

Comment: @Martheli I'm importing either SocketIO or Starscream.

Comment: you need to post your code where you are receiving the error.

Comment: @Martheli It is coming during the import the statements.

Comment: did you install the library via cocoa pods?

Comment: @Martheli yes I did!

Comment: you should include that in your question so people know.